# dates as series in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got the following dataframe:

```
df.head()


t0  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
2015-10-27  100 122.418382  73.302960   70.638446   46.080766   65.134674
2015-10-29  100 167.003327  100.000000  96.365066   62.863445   88.856812
2015-11-09  100 252.576921  151.240653  145.743154  95.075085   134.387623
2015-11-16  100 224.504745  134.431301  129.544812  84.508147   119.451369
2015-12-16  100 152.122482  91.089492   87.778449   57.261993   80.939219
```

If I plot this normally, each t0 becomes a new line.

```
plt.plot()
```

[image: graph]
Now I would like to turn it around:

**I would like the dates to become series and then t0..5 become on the x-axis.** The value of each would be on y axis (as it's now).

Im now considering making a loop for each date but it feels so wrong. Solutions welcome!

Comment: You need to transpose the dataframe, `df.T`. Note that this will result in many lines.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, but it says `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 't5'`. I checked t5, all are just floats.. is this about the label itself?

Comment: I don't know what you tried but yes, the label "t5" is obviously not a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df.T.plot()
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: haha, i thought i tried that too but obviously not. Thank you!